# removeClass removes the class but then adds it back

Tags: jquery, css

I am working with jQuery to animate the menu bar of my webpage. It collapses and moves to left when you scroll down, and is supposed to do the opposite when you scroll back to the top. However, when you reach the top, it moves back part of the way and then snaps back to the left. Here is my code:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
margin-top: 0;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
background-image: url(html-bg2.png);
background-size: 0.5%;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-color: #111111;
overflow: auto;
}

#headbar_left {
position: fixed;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
//margin-top: 3vh;
width: 51vw;
height: 10vh;
background-color: #161616;
border-bottom: 1vh solid #8704ff;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
transform-origin: 100% -50%;
}

#headbar_right {
position: fixed;
right: 0;
margin: 0;
//margin-top: 3vh;
width: 51vw;
height: 10vh;
background-color: #161616;
border-bottom: 1vh solid #8704ff;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}

#circle_logo {
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
width: 14vh;
height: 14vh;
border-radius: 7vh;
background-color: #161616;
left: calc(50vw - 7vh);
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 1vh solid #8704ff;
text-align: center;
line-height: 14vh;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#logo {
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: center;
transition: inherit;
}

.spin {
transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.collapse {
transform: scaleX(0);
}

.move_left {
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out !important;
transform: translateX(calc(7vh - 50vw));
}

#circle_logo:hover {
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out !important;
border-radius: 0;
}

#body_content {
position: absolute;
width: calc(100vw - 28vh);
height: 105vh;
margin-right: 14vh;
margin-left: 14vh;
background-color: #161616;
z-index: -1;
box-shadow: 0 3vh 10vh 4vh black;
color: white;
font-family: "Lucida Console";
padding-top: 21vh;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="uh.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>uh</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="headbar_left"></div>
<div id="headbar_right"></div>
<a href="uh.html"><div id="circle_logo"><img src="html-logo.png" id="logo"></div></a>
<div id="body_content"><center><font size="9.5em"><b>WHAT IS THIS PAGE?</b></font><p>no one knows</center></div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() !== 0) {
        $("#circle_logo").addClass('spin');
        $("#headbar_left, #headbar_right").addClass('collapse');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#circle_logo").addClass('move_left');
            $("#logo").attr("src", "up-arrow.png");
            $("a").attr("href", "#top");
        }, 500);    
    }
    else {
        $("#circle_logo").removeClass('move_left');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#circle_logo").removeClass('spin');
            $("#headbar_left, #headbar_right").removeClass('collapse');
            $("#logo").attr("src", "html-logo.png");
            $("a").attr("href", "uh.html");
        }, 500);   
    }
});
</script>
</html>
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

**EDIT:** I fixed it. Here's the new javascript:

```
var a = 1;

function remove() {
    if (a === 0) {
        $("#circle_logo").removeClass('move_left');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#circle_logo").removeClass('spin');
            $("#headbar_left, #headbar_right").removeClass('collapse');
            $("#logo").attr("src", "html-logo.png");
            $("a").attr("href", "uh.html");
        }, 500);
        a = 1;
    }
}

function add() {
    if (a === 1) {
        $("#circle_logo").addClass('spin');
        $("#headbar_left, #headbar_right").addClass('collapse');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#circle_logo").addClass('move_left');
            $("#logo").attr("src", "up-arrow.png");
            $("a").attr("href", "#top");
        }, 500);
        a = 0;
    }
}

$(document).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() !== 0) {
        add();
    }
    else {
        remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Use one `setTimeout` out of conditional statements. Seems like both blocks (if and else) are evaluated since blocks do not define new scope.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to implement this, can you elaborate please?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you where trying was pretty closed. But the problem was where you set the `setTimeOut()` that has been triggered on almost every pixel you scrolled so many, many, many times. Like this it's fixed and what you want I think..:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() !== 0) {
            $("#circle_logo").addClass('spin');
            $("#headbar_left, #headbar_right").addClass('collapse');
                $("#circle_logo").addClass('move_left');
                $("#logo").attr("src", "up-arrow.png");
                $("a").attr("href", "#top");
        } else {
            $("#circle_logo").removeClass('move_left');
                $("#circle_logo").removeClass('spin');
                $("#headbar_left, #headbar_right").removeClass('collapse');
                $("#logo").attr("src", "html-logo.png");
                $("a").attr("href", "uh.html");
        }
    }, 50);    
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
margin-top: 0;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
background-image: url(html-bg2.png);
background-size: 0.5%;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-color: #111111;
overflow: auto;
}

#headbar_left {
position: fixed;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
//margin-top: 3vh;
width: 51vw;
height: 10vh;
background-color: #161616;
border-bottom: 1vh solid #8704ff;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
transform-origin: 100% -50%;
}

#headbar_right {
position: fixed;
right: 0;
margin: 0;
//margin-top: 3vh;
width: 51vw;
height: 10vh;
background-color: #161616;
border-bottom: 1vh solid #8704ff;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}

#circle_logo {
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
width: 14vh;
height: 14vh;
border-radius: 7vh;
background-color: #161616;
left: calc(50vw - 7vh);
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 1vh solid #8704ff;
text-align: center;
line-height: 14vh;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#logo {
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: center;
transition: inherit;
}

.spin {
transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.collapse {
transform: scaleX(0);
}

.move_left {
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out !important;
transform: translateX(calc(7vh - 50vw));
}

#circle_logo:hover {
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out !important;
border-radius: 0;
}

#body_content {
position: absolute;
width: calc(100vw - 28vh);
height: 105vh;
margin-right: 14vh;
margin-left: 14vh;
background-color: #161616;
z-index: -1;
box-shadow: 0 3vh 10vh 4vh black;
color: white;
font-family: "Lucida Console";
padding-top: 21vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="headbar_left"></div>
<div id="headbar_right"></div>
<a href="uh.html"><div id="circle_logo"><img src="html-logo.png" id="logo"></div></a>
<div id="body_content"><center><font size="9.5em"><b>WHAT IS THIS PAGE?</b></font><p>no one knows</center></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work quite how I want. The point is to have the movement happen after the menu bar collapses when you scroll down, and before when you scroll back up

Comment: @maknel updated the answer, lowered the timeOut to 50 instead of the 500 from before. Either way, doing something before something happens will not be possible, never, no matter of what programming language. First always something has to happen, then you can do something/react with/on it.

Comment: All right, thanks. I think that gives me an idea of how to fix it.

Comment: Yep, I fixed it! Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @maknel post your answer or please consider accepting one of the given answers if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I've just removed first `setTimeout(function()` (but not code inside it).

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() !== 0) {
        $("#circle_logo").addClass('spin');
        $("#headbar_left, #headbar_right").addClass('collapse');
       
            $("#circle_logo").addClass('move_left');
            $("#logo").attr("src", "up-arrow.png");
            $("a").attr("href", "#top");
            
    }
    else {
        $("#circle_logo").removeClass('move_left');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#circle_logo").removeClass('spin');
            $("#headbar_left, #headbar_right").removeClass('collapse');
            $("#logo").attr("src", "html-logo.png");
            $("a").attr("href", "uh.html");
        }, 500);   
    }
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
margin-top: 0;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
background-image: url(html-bg2.png);
background-size: 0.5%;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-color: #111111;
overflow: auto;
}

#headbar_left {
position: fixed;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
//margin-top: 3vh;
width: 51vw;
height: 10vh;
background-color: #161616;
border-bottom: 1vh solid #8704ff;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
transform-origin: 100% -50%;
}

#headbar_right {
position: fixed;
right: 0;
margin: 0;
//margin-top: 3vh;
width: 51vw;
height: 10vh;
background-color: #161616;
border-bottom: 1vh solid #8704ff;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}

#circle_logo {
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
width: 14vh;
height: 14vh;
border-radius: 7vh;
background-color: #161616;
left: calc(50vw - 7vh);
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 1vh solid #8704ff;
text-align: center;
line-height: 14vh;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#logo {
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: center;
transition: inherit;
}

.spin {
transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.collapse {
transform: scaleX(0);
}

.move_left {
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out !important;
transform: translateX(calc(7vh - 50vw));
}

#circle_logo:hover {
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out !important;
border-radius: 0;
}

#body_content {
position: absolute;
width: calc(100vw - 28vh);
height: 105vh;
margin-right: 14vh;
margin-left: 14vh;
background-color: #161616;
z-index: -1;
box-shadow: 0 3vh 10vh 4vh black;
color: white;
font-family: "Lucida Console";
padding-top: 21vh;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="uh.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>uh</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="headbar_left"></div>
<div id="headbar_right"></div>
<a href="uh.html"><div id="circle_logo"><img src="html-logo.png" id="logo"></div></a>
<div id="body_content"><center><font size="9.5em"><b>WHAT IS THIS PAGE?</b></font><p>no one knows</center></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This nearly works, but I want circle_logo to rotate and headbar_left and headbar_right to collapse before circle_logo moves to the left

Comment: Can you write it "step by step" to make me sure that I understand what do you want right? For example... "scrollDown: 1.start rotating circle logo, start collapsing headbars; 2. finish rotating; 3. finish collapsing; ". Really, I'm just not sure about that I understand you good. I see you're changing images too, but only because of reading code I know that you want it ;)

Comment: Sorry for being so unclear about it! I actually solved it myself, but your answer helped me a lot, thanks.